# Create glue string with mixture of single and double quotes

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-glue

I am trying to create a string using the `glue` package in `R`
which is a **mixture of 'single'** and **"double"** quotes.

As a reprex, consider the following type of `SQL` query
string I want to build:

```
CREATE TABLE fact_final_table AS 
(SELECT tab1.id,
    AVG(tab2."MV") FILTER (WHERE tab2.record_dt BETWEEN tab1.start_date::date - integer '7'
                                                      AND tab1.start_date::date - integer '1') AS "mv_avg_1w",
    AVG(tab2."MV") FILTER (WHERE tab2.record_dt BETWEEN tab1.start_date::date - integer '14'
                                                      AND tab1.start_date::date - integer '1') AS "mv_avg_2w"
FROM (SELECT id,
             start_date,
             point
      FROM base_tab
      WHERE mpfb.start_date::date >= '01-01-2000'::date) AS tab1
LEFT JOIN ghcnd_observations AS tab2
    ON (tab2.record_dt BETWEEN (tab1.start_date::date - integer '180')
                           AND (tab1.start_date::date - integer '1')
        AND ST_DWithin(tab1.point, tab2.location, 0.5))
GROUP BY tab1.id);
```

As you can see it is a combination of single and double quotes,
which are important to preserve literally as written above. For
example the `tab2."MV"` has double quotes, and `tab1.start_date::date - integer '7' AND tab1.start_date::date - integer '1'` has single
quotes which need to be preserved literally.

This string also needs to be built using parameters.
I tried the following in `R` using `glue`, but couldn't get it
to work.

```
var1       <- "MV"
var1_lowcase <- "mv"
lag_days   <- 180
var_date   <- as.Date("2000-01-01")
var_dwithin <- 0.5

glue::glue(
"CREATE TABLE fact_final_table AS 
(SELECT tab1.id,
    AVG(tab2."{var1}") FILTER (WHERE tab2.record_dt BETWEEN tab1.start_date::date - integer '7'
                           AND tab1.start_date::date - integer '1') AS "{var1_lowcase}_avg_1w",
    AVG(tab2."{var1}") FILTER (WHERE tab2.record_dt BETWEEN tab1.start_date::date - integer '14'
                           AND tab1.start_date::date - integer '1') AS "{var1_lowcase}_avg_2w"
    FROM (SELECT id,
          start_date,
          point
          FROM base_tab
          WHERE mpfb.start_date::date >= '{format(var_date, "%d-%m-%Y")}'::date) AS tab1
    LEFT JOIN ghcnd_observations AS tab2
    ON (tab2.record_dt BETWEEN (tab1.start_date::date - integer '{lag_days}')
        AND (tab1.start_date::date - integer '1')
        AND ST_DWithin(tab1.point, tab2.location, {var_dwithin}))
    GROUP BY tab1.id);")
```

This does not work unfortunately due to single/double quotes not being
escaped correctly in `glue::glue(...)`.

Could anyone please assist here with minimal amount
of breaking of the required output string? I'm not sure if this is easily
feasible. I would appreciate any other `tidy` approaches e.g. using `stringr` as well for example, as I would like this to be `%>%` friendly.
I've briefly looked at `glue::glue_sql` but didn't know how to directly
apply it here. I'd be grateful to learn how to use it here as applicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I looked into this in more detail since yesterday, and
it does appear that `glue` does have functions to [make single
and double quotes explicit](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue/issues/135) i.e. `glue::single_quote()` and
`glue::double_quote()`.

Similar to the (helpful) response by @ronakshah, I managed 
the following, which is more explicit (for code readability):

```
var1       <- "MV"
var1_lowcase <- "mv"
lag_days   <- 180
var_date   <- as.Date("2000-01-01")
var_dwithin <- 0.5

glue::glue(
    "CREATE TABLE fact_final_table AS 
   (SELECT tab1.id,
   AVG(tab2.{glue::double_quote(var1)}) FILTER (WHERE tab2.record_dt BETWEEN tab1.start_date::date - integer '7'
   AND tab1.start_date::date - integer '1') AS {glue::double_quote(glue::glue({var1_lowcase},'_avg_1w'))},
   AVG(tab2.{glue::double_quote(var1)}) FILTER (WHERE tab2.record_dt BETWEEN tab1.start_date::date - integer '14'
   AND tab1.start_date::date - integer '1') AS {glue::double_quote(glue::glue({var1_lowcase},'_avg_2w'))}
   FROM (SELECT id,
         start_date,
          point
   FROM base_tab
    WHERE mpfb.start_date::date >= {glue::single_quote(format(var_date, '%d-%m-%Y'))}::date) 
  AS tab1
   LEFT JOIN ghcnd_observations AS tab2
   ON (tab2.record_dt BETWEEN (tab1.start_date::date - integer '{lag_days}')
   AND (tab1.start_date::date - integer '1')
   AND ST_DWithin(tab1.point, tab2.location, {var_dwithin}))
   GROUP BY tab1.id);")
```

Which returns the main string I required. Hope this helps others
who had similar `glue` requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Try to escape the double quotes :

```
glue::glue(
   "CREATE TABLE fact_final_table AS 
   (SELECT tab1.id,
   AVG(tab2.\"{var1}\") FILTER (WHERE tab2.record_dt BETWEEN tab1.start_date::date - integer '7'
   AND tab1.start_date::date - integer '1') AS \"{var1_lowcase}_avg_1w\",
   AVG(tab2.\"{var1}\") FILTER (WHERE tab2.record_dt BETWEEN tab1.start_date::date - integer '14'
   AND tab1.start_date::date - integer '1') AS \"{var1_lowcase}_avg_2w\"
   FROM (SELECT id,
         start_date,
          point
   FROM base_tab
    WHERE mpfb.start_date::date >= '{format(var_date, \"%d-%m-%Y\")}'::date) 
  AS tab1
   LEFT JOIN ghcnd_observations AS tab2
   ON (tab2.record_dt BETWEEN (tab1.start_date::date - integer '{lag_days}')
   AND (tab1.start_date::date - integer '1')
   AND ST_DWithin(tab1.point, tab2.location, {var_dwithin}))
   GROUP BY tab1.id);")
```

which returns :

```
#CREATE TABLE fact_final_table AS 
#(SELECT tab1.id,
#AVG(tab2."MV") FILTER (WHERE tab2.record_dt BETWEEN tab1.start_date::date #- integer '7'
#AND tab1.start_date::date - integer '1') AS "mv_avg_1w",
#AVG(tab2."MV") FILTER (WHERE tab2.record_dt BETWEEN tab1.start_date::date #- integer '14'
#AND tab1.start_date::date - integer '1') AS "mv_avg_2w"
#FROM (SELECT id,
#start_date,
#point
#FROM base_tab
#WHERE mpfb.start_date::date >= '01-01-2000'::date) AS tab1
#LEFT JOIN ghcnd_observations AS tab2
#ON (tab2.record_dt BETWEEN (tab1.start_date::date - integer '180')
#AND (tab1.start_date::date - integer '1')
#AND ST_DWithin(tab1.point, tab2.location, 0.5))
#GROUP BY tab1.id);
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer. I worked on a similar approach yesterday, and found that there is a more explicit approach using `glue::single_quote()` and `glue::double_quote` functions. See my answer below, which I will likely go with